# Revert C# class template to default one

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, stylecop

I have just installed StyleCop 4.5 and default templates have been replaced with some I don't really appreciate right now. How can I revert it to default?

Comment: It happens that it is sometimes enough to ask to find the answer - I replaced Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\Class.zip with old one in Class.zip.bak ;) edit: eh, It doesn't change anything :(

Comment: solved - this link was very helpful: http://blog.palelocust.com/?p=27 I need also invoke devenv /setup after replacing that zips.

Comment: @mrzepa: If you've answered your own question, write it up as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Don't worry, I will do that in the right time :P I would have done it long ago, but there's time constraints...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved that.
There's possibility to revert that changes, because visual has backups for old classes templates.

All templates are placed in folder like this:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033

After reverting there is one more thing to do, open cmd and enter command:
devenv /setup

This will update changes.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure which exact version you are using, but on the latest version (4.6.3.0  which should be equivalent to the latest 4.5 but with R# 6.0 compat) if you rerun the StyleCop installer, you can change the installation including uninstalling the VS templates while leaving the rest of the installation intact.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem, but took me a bit to figure out that it was stylecop that had caused my templates to change.(I had not coded in a while after installing the new stylecop version)

Anyways, to fix this issue, I installed the latest version of style cop and then un-installed.  They have fixed the later version installer to ensure it reverts your visual studio templates back to the vs default templates.

Finally, I installed the latest version again and during the install I made sure to **Exclude updating the visual studio templates**.

I hope this helps someone else.